# Spark repartition do not divide data to all executors

Tags: apache-spark

I have 8 executors with 4 core each , I repartition a rdd to 32. I expects all 8 executors play a part on on the next action that i call on the repartitioned data. But seems like sometime 3 executors participate and sometimes 4 but not more than that.

How can i ensure that the data gets divided on all executors?

rdd.repartition(32).foreachPartition{ part =>
          updateMem(part)
      }
The last part calls inser/update into memsql.

Comment: Is the rdd in any sort of format, like a K/V pair?  You might have a low number of keys, so the repartition puts the same keys on the same executors, or you could be incredibly unlucky such that your keys all have hash values that mod 32 to a number.

Comment: RDD is of type case class. The data inside the case class is very unique, almost 95%.

Comment: How many machines are in play here ? Does the data reside (almost) equally on all these machines ?  I doubt if data locality is playing its part here

Comment: Data is brought in from Kafka , since the topic have 4 partitions looks like initially it comes in with 4 partitions only. Data is not local and I do store it in memory only  with this. .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

Comment: Is it possible that initial 4 partitions stored in memory is getting persisted in only few machines and the repartition call does not redistribute the data across. I have started the job with 16 executors 4 cores each, 32 executers s with 1 core or 2 core, none of them worked.

Comment: You can very easily check where the RDD is getting persisted by looking at the storage section of the UI

Comment: Thats what the question is , its in 4 partitions  that is persisted in only 4 executors at max, but then i have an an explicit repartition call with 32 partitions as ask, it creates 32 partitions but the partitions are still on 4 nodes and do not distribute equally on other executors which are available to use.

Comment: It will not repartition it the way you want it to be Locality seems to play a role here. You should do 32 partitions on Kafka to make your all machines utilised. Since its just 4, the four machines get the data and then repartition amongst the same set of machines because of data locality.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is valid only if you are using AWS- EMR.
I dont think it is correct to say that you have 8 executors of 4 cores each. here is the explanation. Say, I am using m3.2xlarge machine (EMR).

- each machine contains 30 GB memory(total) 8 vcores
- There is no way that you can use all the 30 GB memory for executors
  as machine would need some memory for its own use.
- You would like to leave enough memory for machine own use (like OS
  and other usage) so that there will not be any system failure.
- say, you want to leave 10GB memory for machines then you are left
  with 20GB memory
- In 20 GB memory I can have 6 executors (3GB each, 6*3GB =18GB) , can
  have 4 executors (5GB each, 4*5GB = 20GB) etc
- so, you can decide the number of executors depending upon your need
  on memory for each executor.

To be specific to your use case, look into your total memory available in each machine and the spark-conf(/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf) for these two parameters and adjust accordingly.

- spark.executor.memory
- spark.executor.cores